# How i can add input field on specific selection in depended drop down

Tags: html, laravel, dropdown

How i can add input field on specific selection in depended drop down 
i want to show input field when user select other option in drop down  list.
Like when someone want to add something more that is not in the list he can add manually.
List will be too big I'm just showing the first three categorizes

Here is my code:

```
    @extends('layout/header')
@include('layout/sidebar')
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1 class="motetreports_heading"></h1>
                {{-- first sequnce --}}
                <form action="/atgard" method="post">
                    @csrf

                        <table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
                          <tr>
                            <td width="41%" align="right" valign="middle">Category1 :</td>
                            <td width="59%" align="left" valign="middle">
                              <select name="category1" id="category1">
                                <option value="">Select Category1</option>
                                <option value="home_ware">Home Ware</option>
                                <option value="education">Education</option>
                                <option value="books">Other</option>
                              </select>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td align="right" valign="middle">Category2 :</td>
                            <td align="left" valign="middle">
                              <select disabled="disabled" class="subcat" id="category2" name="category2">
                                <option value>Select Category2</option>
                                <!-- Home Ware -->
                                <optgroup data-rel="home_ware">
                                  <option value="air-conditioners_coolers">Air-Conditioners/Coolers</option>
                                  <option value="audio-video">Audio/Video</option>
                                  <option value="beddings">Beddings</option>
                                  <option value="camera">Camera</option>
                                  <option value="cell-phones">Cell Phones</option>
                                </optgroup>
                                <!-- Education -->
                                <optgroup data-rel="education">
                                  <option value="Colleges">Colleges</option>
                                  <option value="Institutes">Institutes</option>
                                  <option value="Schools">Schools</option>
                                  <option value="Tuitions">Tuitions</option>
                                  <option value="Universities">Universities</option>
                                </optgroup>
                                <!-- Books -->
                                <optgroup data-rel="books">
                                  <option value="College Books">College Books</option>
                                  <option value="Engineering">Engineering</option>
                                  <option value="Magazines">Magazines</option>
                                  <option value="Medicine">Medicine</option>
                                  <option value="References">References</option>
                                </optgroup>
                              </select>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td align="right" valign="middle">Category3 :</td>
                            <td align="left" valign="middle">
                              <select disabled="disabled" class="subcat" id="category3" name="category3">
                                <option value>Select Category3</option>
                                <!-- Home Ware -->
                                <optgroup data-rel="home_ware">
                                  <option value="foo1">category3 home ware 1</option>
                                  <option value="foo2">category3 home ware 2</option>
                                </optgroup>
                                <!-- Education -->
                                <optgroup data-rel="education">
                                  <option value="foo3">category3 Education 1</option>
                                  <option value="foo4">category3 Education 2</option>
                                </optgroup>
                                <!-- Books -->
                                <optgroup data-rel="books">
                                  <option value="foo5">category3 Books 1</option>
                                  <option value="foo6">category3 Books 2</option>
                                </optgroup>
                              </select>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>


                    <button type="submit" style="width: 100px;" class="btn btn-primary">Skicka</button>
                </form>

                <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function(){

    var $cat = $("#category1"),
        $subcat = $(".subcat");

    var optgroups = {};

    $subcat.each(function(i,v){
        var $e = $(v);
        var _id = $e.attr("id");
            optgroups[_id] = {};
            $e.find("optgroup").each(function(){
        var _r = $(this).data("rel");
        $(this).find("option").addClass("is-dyn");
        optgroups[_id][_r] = $(this).html();
            });
    });
    $subcat.find("optgroup").remove();

    var _lastRel;
    $cat.on("change",function(){
        var _rel = $(this).val();
        if(_lastRel === _rel) return true;
        _lastRel = _rel;
        $subcat.find("option").attr("style","");
        $subcat.val("");
        $subcat.find(".is-dyn").remove();
        if(!_rel) return $subcat.prop("disabled",true);
        $subcat.each(function(){
            var $el = $(this);
          var _id = $el.attr("id");
          $el.append(optgroups[_id][_rel]);
        });
        $subcat.prop("disabled",false);
    });

});
                </script>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</div>
<!-- /#page-wrapper -->

</div>
<!-- /#wrapper -->

@include('layout/footer')
```

Comment: fyi, `<form>` inside a `<form>` is invalid

Comment: i can understand !
but i need solution for what i want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should put an `document.getElementById("theselectid").selected = true;` or something that will indicate that it was checked, then: inside if, `document.getElementById("theidofinput").disabled = false;document.getElementById("theidofinput").style.opacity = 1.0;` or something.